# Update a column value in db

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to subtract the value of **'stk_on_hand'** field with some value and update it.And for this what i have tried is

```
        $this->db->select('co_q_id,co_stk_id,co_req_quantity');
        $this->db->from('customer_order');                 
        $this->db->where('co_num',1);  
        $result=$this->db->get();  
        foreach($result->result() as $row){                                 
            $stkArray[] = array(
            'stk_id'=>$row->co_stk_id,
            'stk_on_hand' =>'stk_on_hand - ' . (int) $row->co_req_quantity
            ); 
        $this->db->update_batch('ms_stock_list',$stkArray, 'stk_id');
```

But after executing this I'm getting **'stk_on_hand'** as **0**.Somebody please help .

Answer (score 0):

**First** check on your Database column if 'stk_on_hand' is an varchar
**Second** revome the (int) before

```
$row->co_req_quantity
```